# Running a command in the virtual machine from host system

Tags: linux, vmware-player

I have a virtual machine with linux 15.04 installed into it.
I have an image processing application. I have to send some data and a command line instruction to the operating system in virtual machine directly from host.

Is it possible to do it, if so, any pointer would help!

**Update**

I found something with VirtualBox in the [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153894/launch-an-application-in-windows-from-the-ubuntu-desktop).

However, I am using VMWare and the process is reversed, sending the command to linux from windows.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could use [vmrun](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/vix162_vmrun_command.pdf) to control virtual machines running VMware on host.

Comment: I have seen this command but most of it is to control the VMs. I  could not find any for running the commands on VMware. If you know anything specific, that would help.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Because your question states that you want to run a command line instruction to a VM, which can be done with `runProgramInGuest` in the given link (p 10).